# Which metro bundler settings are needed to resolve React Native's internal modules?

Tags: react-native

I have initialized a new React Native project (0.57.4) with `react-native init` and am trying to run the [Metro](https://facebook.github.io/metro/) bundler on it programmatically; however, it is unable to resolve React Native's internal modules (e.g. `AccessibilityInfo`) which is the first module `require`d in the React Native source:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `/myproject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Following instructions to clear caches does not help.

Here is the code I am using to run the `Metro` bundler programmatically:

```js
const path = require('path')
const metro = require('metro')

const entry = './index.js'
const out = './build/index.bundle'
const platform = 'ios'
const root = process.cwd()

build()

async function build() {

  const config = {
    resolver: {
      providesModuleNodeModules: ['react-native'],
    },
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer'),
    },
    serializer: {},
    server: {},
    projectRoot: root,
    watchFolders: [root, path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'metro')],
  }

  const opts = { dev: false, entry, optimize: true, out, platform, sourceMap: true }

  return await metro.runBuild(config, opts)
}
```

I suspect I may be missing a setting that will allow `Metro` to resolve React Natives modules marked with the `@providesModule` header comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By watching what configuration React Native was passing to Metro, I found some additional settings that were required to make things work, notably `hasteImplModulePath`, `getModulesRunBeforeMainModule`, and `getPolyfills`.

```
const config = {
  resolver: {
    providesModuleNodeModules: ['react-native'],
    resolverMainFields: ['react-native', 'browser', 'main'],
    hasteImplModulePath: path.join(root, 'node_modules/react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js'),
    blacklistRE: /(.*\/__fixtures__\/.*|node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*|website\/node_modules\/.*|heapCapture\/bundle\.js|.*\/__tests__\/.*)$/,
  },
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer')
  },
  serializer: {
    getModulesRunBeforeMainModule: () => [
      path.join(root, 'node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js')
    ],
    getPolyfills: require(path.join(root, 'node_modules/react-native/rn-get-polyfills')),
  },
  server: {},
  projectRoot: root,
  watchFolders: [root, path.join(root, 'node_modules'), path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
}
```